# OpenAuth / Google API donet An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: google-api, dotnetopenauth, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I am using open auth with google api's to authenticate users using .NET. I have been receiving this error on a sever with a high level of requests. On smaller servers there is no issue. I can't find any documentation to help me verify that this is related to sending to many requests. I thought perhaps someone else has seen these excpetions and found the root cause. Thanks!

Edit: Added code sample

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(svcAccount_FilePath, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

var provider = new AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, certificate)
{
    ServiceAccountUser = username,
    ServiceAccountId = label,
    Scope = scope
};

var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(provider, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

// Create the service.
var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    Authenticator = auth
});

var listReq = service.Users.List();
listReq.Domain = emailServer.domainServerIP;
listReq.MaxResults = 1;

Users results = listReq.Execute()
```

Exception thrown on the listReq.Execute()

```
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: Web request to 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token' failed. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetRequestStreamCore(HttpWebRequest request)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post your code. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: It looks like you are either using a proxy or are behind a firewall and having issues

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be mixing [dotnetopenauth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) with the [Google .net client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client).  that is not going to work at all.  The [Google .net client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) has its own auth module.

The following code is ripped from my sample project.
 you apear to be trying to use a [service account](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Admin%20Directory%20API/directory_v1/ServiceAccount.cs)

```
public static DirectoryService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, string[] scopes)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                throw new Exception("Path to the service account credentials file is required.");
            if (!File.Exists(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                throw new Exception("The service account credentials file does not exist at: " + serviceAccountCredentialFilePath);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountEmail))
                throw new Exception("ServiceAccountEmail is required.");                

            // For Json file
            if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".json")
            {
                GoogleCredential credential;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                         .CreateScoped(scopes);
                }

                // Create the  Analytics service.
                return new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Directory Service account Authentication Sample",
                });
            }
            else if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".p12")
            {   // If its a P12 file

                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = scopes
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                // Create the  Directory service.
                return new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Directory Authentication Sample",
                });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unsupported Service accounts credentials.");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountDirectoryFailed", ex);
        }
    }
```

I am not very familiar with [dotnetopenauth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) but it looks like you are either behind a proxy or a fire wall and its not letting you though.